# изменить содержимое тега на определенной странице в Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Как изменить на определенной странице нужно изменить содержимое тега, вот этого! table class="table term-marks"
Есть вот такой код, но он работает на всю страницу!

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/2/gi, '4');


            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сразу видно что код скопировали первый попавшийся, дабы скрыть отсутствие своих попыток. Плохо, очень плохо!

Comment: Да? ОК, что делает код, почему именно это Вы так написали?

Comment: я пытался вот так      document.getElementByClassName("table term-marks").innerHTML = document.getElementByClassName("table term-marks").innerHTML.replace(/4/ig, '3');

Comment: Уже лучше, но всё ещё холодно. Похоже на рандомную вставку.

Comment: нет это же не рандомная вставка, ну так поможете может?

Comment: мне ооочень нужно!

Comment: Очень нужно - это для фрилансеров.

Comment: ну тогда зачем же вы комментируете, если не хотите помочь!

Comment: Хочу (иначе сидел бы я тут!). Но когда кто-то сам себе не помогает, а просит сделать за них - это печаль и не помощь вообще. Даже неясно что нужно (изменить на странице - непонятно).

Comment: кароче скажу прямо искал очень много, разбираюсь только в html и css ну и не много в php, вот пытаюсь сделать расширение которое меняло бы цифры из тега table а теге table находятся очень много тегов td вот если  он там находит 2 или 3 он меняет их на 4 вооот)

Comment: ну так что?)))))

Comment: Ответил, постарался с подробностями. Если непонятно - спрашивайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используем:

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - поиск элементов по CSS-выражению (`.` - класс, для поиска с несколькими классами одновременно, соединяем их **без** пробела: `.classNameOne.classNameTwo`).
- [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) - распределяем найденное в массив и проходим циклом по найденному.
- [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) - поиск подстроки (как `indexOf`, только удобнее в определённых случаях).

Вот пример:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.some.thing')].forEach(n => {
  let value = n.innerHTML;
  
  if(value.trim().includes('ещё'))  // Если в ноде есть нужный текст
    n.innerHTML = value + ' (!!!)'; // Делаем своих грязные или не очень делишки!
});
```

```css
.some{
  color: lightblue;
}
.thing{
  background: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div>Это <span class='some thing'>выделенное</span> слово и <span class='some thing'>ещё</span> одно!</div>
```

Comment: не работает на моем примере, щас скрин дам)может поймете
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/251117/kLl3kKff

Comment: Кидаете школоту на "Супер исправлятель оценок 3000"? Что именно не работает? Пример ясно показывает что идея работает, может Вы просто тупо скопировали без исправления?

Comment: спаси мою судьбу , я просто 2 двойки не успею исправить!

Comment: А зачем Вам это вообще? Реальные оценки это не исправит (если нет эксплойта на сервер школы и компромата на учителя), разве что родителям показать липу? Позвонят в школу и всё.